# When seting setState(), occur a problem in the .map(). New in React-Native

Tags: react-native

I'm  new in RN, so this code may be wrong.
The error is : "TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...kanjis.map...')"

This error happen when I try to set state "setKanjis(item)", the error occurs in the return(
{kanjis.map((item) => {}
)

```
const [kanjis, setKanjis] = useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {
    fetch(URL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        const result = responseJson.kanjis.filter(
          (item) => item.should_learn == 0,
        );
        setKanjis(result);
      });
  }, []);

 kanjis.map((item) => {
      return item.selected == true
        ? ((item.should_learn = 1), setKanjis(item))
        : item.should_learn;
    });

 return (
    <View style={styles.kanjiView}>
        {kanjis.map((item) => {
          return (
            <View>
              {item.selected == true ? (
                
              ) : (
               
              )}
            </View>
          );
        })}
      </View>

      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.addButton} onPress={addKanji}>
        <Text style={styles.addButtonText}>Add</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
 );
};
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: This is wrong on so many levels. Before diving into `React-native`, I recommend learning`React` first. It's better if you understand what you write. I don't see that you've understand how React works in general.

Comment: Here, you're setting an blank array onto your state. There's no point mapping around a blank array. Where are the values inside your array? Where is item coming from inside your map? And this is just invalid syntax, I reckon `((item.should_learn = 1), setKanjis(item))`

Comment: Sorry, I didin't put all my code, i'm maping an API, I'll edit this part. Prateek, do you know how I set this state setKanjis?

Comment: You cannot do async actions inside useEffect
Take a look here:  https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data

Comment: This is not a valid syntax. What are you trying to do here. `? ((item.should_learn = 1), setKanjis(item))`

Comment: @Aymen That is valid inside the useEffect. You can do async calls inside the useEffect.

Comment: I'm setting a new value to `kanji.should_learn` and trying to update the state of `kanjis`  with `setKanjis(item)`. To my app react to this changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your backend api call and setState are both async functions, so that's why `kanjis.map` is returning an error. To resolve that error, you can move the map function inside the promise resolving code.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    fetch(URL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        const result = responseJson.kanjis.filter(
          (item) => item.should_learn == 0,
        );
        setKanjis(result);
      result.map((item) => {
         return item.selected == true
           ? ((item.should_learn = 1), setKanjis(item))
           : item.should_learn;
    });
      });
  }, []);
```

please note that i changed `kanjis.map` to `result.map` reason being that setState is async. There are other things wrong with your code, so you will still see errors. For example, you are still referencing the state variable `kanjis` in your return

```
<View style={styles.kanjiView}>
        {kanjis.map((item) => {
          return (
            <View>
              {item.selected == true ? (
                
              ) : (
               
              )}
            </View>
          );
        })}
      </View>
```

One way to work around that is to render a loading page (or a spinner) before the back api resolves. you simply check the state variable kanjis, if it's undefined render spinner. If it's defined render your data.